Why is my Color Selector not working with opacity
I'm encountering an issue with my color selector where adjusting the opacity doesn't seem to function correctly. Instead of applying the opacity setting to the selected color as expected, it consistently turns the color white before adjusting the opacity. This results in the opacity settings not affecting the colors I choose in the way I intend them to. Essentially, despite my efforts to modify the opacity, the selected colors do not reflect these changes accurately.
Here is my code for the opacity and saving the color to the panel. . .
namespace System_Tools
{
    public partial class colorpickerPage : UserControl
    {
        private Color selectedColor = Color.White; 

        public colorpickerPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            colorWheelPictureBox.MouseClick += colorWheelPictureBox_MouseClick;
            opacityTrackBar.Scroll += opacityTrackBar_Scroll;
            UpdateColorDisplays(selectedColor);
        }

        private Form1 parentForm;

        public void SetParentForm(Form1 form)
        {
            parentForm = form;
        }

        public string ColorToHex(Color color)
        {
            return $"#{color.R:X2}{color.G:X2}{color.B:X2}";
        }

        public string ColorToHSV(Color color)
        {
            double hue = color.GetHue();
            double saturation = color.GetSaturation();
            double brightness = color.GetBrightness();
            return $"{hue:F2}, {saturation:F2}, {brightness:F2}";
        }

        public string ColorToHSL(Color color)
        {
            double r = color.R / 255.0;
            double g = color.G / 255.0;
            double b = color.B / 255.0;

            double max = Math.Max(r, Math.Max(g, b));
            double min = Math.Min(r, Math.Min(g, b));

            double h = color.GetHue();
            double l = (max + min) / 2.0;
            double s = (max == min) ? 0 : (l <= 0.5 ? (max - min) / (max + min) : (max - min) / (2 - max - min));

            return $"{h:F2}, {s:F2}, {l:F2}";
        }

        public string ColorToCMYK(Color color)
        {
            float r = color.R / 255f;
            float g = color.G / 255f;
            float b = color.B / 255f;

            float k = 1 - Math.Max(r, Math.Max(g, b));
            float c = (1 - r - k) / (1 - k);
            float m = (1 - g - k) / (1 - k);
            float y = (1 - b - k) / (1 - k);

            return $"{c:F2}, {m:F2}, {y:F2}, {k:F2}";
        }

        private void colorWheelPictureBox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(colorWheelPictureBox.Image);
            Color selectedColor = bitmap.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y);
            UpdateColorDisplays(selectedColor);

            if (selectedColor.A != 0)
            {
                hexTextBox.Text = ColorToHex(selectedColor);
                rgbTextBox.Text = $"{selectedColor.R}, {selectedColor.G}, {selectedColor.B}";
                hsvTextBox.Text = ColorToHSV(selectedColor);
                hslTextBox.Text = ColorToHSL(selectedColor);
                cmykTextBox.Text = ColorToCMYK(selectedColor);
            }
        }

        private void opacityTrackBar_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateColorDisplays(selectedColor);
        }

        private void UpdateColorDisplays(Color color)
        {
            hexTextBox.Text = ColorToHex(color);
            rgbTextBox.Text = $"{color.R}, {color.G}, {color.B}, {color.A}";
            hsvTextBox.Text = ColorToHSV(color);
            hslTextBox.Text = ColorToHSL(color);
            cmykTextBox.Text = ColorToCMYK(color);

            float opacity = opacityTrackBar.Value / 255f;

            Color blendedColor = Color.FromArgb((int)(color.A * opacity), color.R, color.G, color.B);

            colorDisplayPanel.BackColor = blendedColor;
        }
    }
}

I was expecting it for it change the opacity of the color.

What exactly is colorWheelPictureBox?

Its a picture of the color wheel. Literally.

In colorWheelPictureBox_MouseClick(), you're declaring a LOCAL variable called selectedColor, which HIDES your class variable.
This means that in opacityTrackBar_Scroll() it will change back to white because the class variable never gets changed to the selected color...
Change:
    private void colorWheelPictureBox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(colorWheelPictureBox.Image);
        Color selectedColor = bitmap.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y);
        UpdateColorDisplays(selectedColor);

        // ... more code ...

    }

To:
    private void colorWheelPictureBox_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(colorWheelPictureBox.Image);
        selectedColor = bitmap.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y);
        UpdateColorDisplays(selectedColor);

        // ... more code ...

    }

